# Control taskbar blinking event of an other application

Tags: c#

I want to build a c# desktop application which checks the taskbar blinking event of a specific program. When ever the programs taskbar blinking event occurs my application will play an alarm sound. Is it possible and where to start please ?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use something like [EasyHook](https://easyhook.github.io/) and basically replace the processes call to [FlashWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679347(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

However because you don't directly control this application it is likely to be error prone.